# How to show time on page after pressing elevated button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, flutter-layout

I have tried many times to build an elevated button to show live time and date on flutter screen but unfortunately I couldn’t do this. Can any programmer help me ??

This is my code :

```
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  final date =
                      DateFormat('yyyy').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
                  
                });
              },
              child: Text(
                'Show Time',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 150,
            ),
            Text('Date is' + date),
          ],
```

Comment: Remove the "Closed" text from the qn! It's clearly not closed (anymore...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use state variable to show the time. And the DateFormat will be `DateFormat('hh:MM:ss')`. You can find the full [list of DateFormat](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

```dart
class TimerH extends StatefulWidget {
  TimerH({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TimerH> createState() => _TimerHState();
}

class _TimerHState extends State<TimerH> {
  String time = "";

  DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              dateTime = DateTime.now();
              setState(() {
                time = DateFormat('hh:MM:ss').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
              });
            },
            child: Text(
              'Show Time',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 150,
          ),
          Text('Date is' + time),
          Text("${dateTime.hour} ${dateTime.minute} ${dateTime.second}")
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are declaring the `date` variable inside the `setState()`! That makes it a local variable that you can't use anywhere else, outside this `setState()`. Thus, it can't be put in your Widget tree and displayed on the screen, for example.

And another problem is that it's final! If you want it to display *different* times and/or dates each time you press the button, the variable must be mutable, i.e. not final or const.